# using jlongArray in JNI with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I have those two pieces of code, the first is:

```
JNIEXPORT jlongArray* JNICALL Java_com_home_overlay_activity_MainActivity_ProcessPointer(JNIEnv* env, jobject) {

    jlongArray blobs_arr;

    return &blobs_arr;
}
```

and the second is:

```
JNIEXPORT jlongArray JNICALL Java_com_home_overlay_activity_MainActivity_Process(JNIEnv* env, jobject) {

    jlongArray blobs_arr;

    return blobs_arr;
}
```

all I want is to return long array to the java code.

The first runs okay while the second not, is there any issue here with returning a long array this way ??

Comment: which one is generated by javah ?

Comment: I didn't get it. it is solved and I wrote the solution in a comment on the first answer

Comment: If the issue is solved, please write the solution as an answer and accept it. If the question is irrelevant to the issue, please close it. Also, the first snippet is very, very wrong - not only it will not return the data to Java, it's wrong on the C level, too, since it returns the address of a stack variable.

Comment: oh thank you, actually it was just sample for the compilation error, and yes it is irrelevant to the issue and will be closed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application was not reading the jni.h but working .. which is weird, after I set the NDKROOT variable it all worked correctly

Answer (score 1):

There are no pointers in Java, so I think that if the first snippet of code actually works, it will not produce what you want at all. It probably returns the memory address of the C jlongArray.

As for the second piece of code, I can't see any problem with it except that it returns an uninitialized object, maybe NULL, maybe some random memory garbage, which probably causes unexpected behavior on the Java side. Maybe you should try initializing it to NULL in the C part, or try making your code snippet more realistic by actually filing the array so you can test the code behavior in real conditions.

Comment: my problem is not coding, it's compilation, this code does not compile at all, anyway my application was not reading the jni.h but working .. which is weird, after I set the NDKROOT variable it all worked correctly .. but other issues popped up that I can post in another thread ... thank you